# Passing array of dictionary to javascript function from iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

My javascript function needs this type of array:

```
var data = [{
                                    "sale": "202",
                                    "year": "2000"
                                    }, {
                                    "sale": "215",
                                    "year": "2002"
                                    }, {
                                    "sale": "179",
                                    "year": "2004"
                                    }, {
                                    "sale": "199",
                                    "year": "2006"
                                    }, {
                                    "sale": "134",
                                    "year": "2008"
                                    }, {
                                    "sale": "176",
                                    "year": "2010"
                                    }];
```

I want to pass this array as an argument from `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"js_func(%@, %@)", y1Arr, y2Arr]];`

I am passing array of dictionary with this format:

```
({
    x = "663.78";
    y1 = "-0.000";
},
{
    x = "663.88";
    y1 = "0.005";
},
{
    x = "663.98";
    y1 = "0.019";
},
{
    x = "664.08";
    y1 = "-0.001";
}
)
```

But its not working...

Comment: There is no dictionary type in JavaScript. Use `[]` instead of `()` in your last snippet to make it an array. Oh and what is "not working"?

Comment: ({
    x = "663.78";
    y1 = "-0.000";
},
{
    x = "663.88";
    y1 = "0.005";
},
{
    x = "663.98";
    y1 = "0.019";
},
{
    x = "664.08";
    y1 = "-0.001";
}
), this is the log from debugger. My JS function is not getting called. I tried putting and alert there, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pass directly your arrays in the stringWithFormat, you should first convert them into json objects and then pass those json objects (as string representation) to the stringWithFormat

```
NSData *data1 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:y1Arr options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *y1ArrStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *data2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:y2Arr options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *y2ArrStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"js_func(%@, %@)", y1ArrStr, y2ArrStr]];
```

Comment: OK, function is working now.. but when I try ti alert(arrayData), it displays weird values like: [object Object], [object Object]

Comment: For javascript things like { x = "663.78";  y1 = "-0.000"; } are objects, and it doesn't know how to render them inside an alert, try alert(arrayData[0].x)